# Datatable to display a Map of ArrayList of objects in Tomahawk

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, tomahawk

I want to display a `Map<Integer, ArrayList<ObjectBO>>` in a Datatable in Tomahawk. I've tried some possible solutions but nothing seems to be work.

```
<h:panelGrid style="font-family:verdana;font-size:12pt;color:white" columns="1">
    <h:outputText value="Choice 1"></h:outputText>
    <t:dataTable newspaperColumns="1" value="#{startupBean.choiceKeys}" newspaperOrientation="horizontal" var="key">
        <t:column>    
            <h:outputText style="font-family:verdana;font-size:10pt;color:white" value="#{choiceMap[key].ObjectBO.displayName}"/>
        </t:column>
        <t:column>     
            <h:graphicImage width="50" height="50" id="choice" alt="jsf-sun" url="#{choiceMap[Key].ObjectBO.color_url}" value="#{choiceMap[Key].ObjectBO.color_url}"> 
            </h:graphicImage>  
        </t:column> 
    </t:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
```

The backing bean part of it is

```
public List<Integer> getChoiceKeys() {
    System.out.println("in keys");
    List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    keys.addAll(choiceMap.keySet());
    System.out.println("keys " + keys.size());
    return keys;
}
```

Kindly let me know how to traverse through the Map via Datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers are in EL treated as `Long`. In your code, the `key` in `#{choiceMap[key]}` is treated as `Long` and hence the map key never matches because `Integer` is not an instance of `Long`. This approach will work if you use `Long` instead of `Integer` as map key.

Comment: Thanks BalusC! I followed the below link yesterday and it worked. http://nitinbksc.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/java-map-in-jsf/ I was not able to reply to my own question for 8hrs. So couldn't update the post.

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed, converting `Map<K, V>` to `List<Map.Entry<K, V>>` is a different way of achieving the particular functional requirement of showing a `Map` in a `<h:dataTable>`.